# "...,который.... и которая..."

Tags: грамматика

Как вы думаете, корректна ли грамматически фраза 
***"Жили-были Петя и Маша, который любил её(,) и которая любила его".*** 
Если да, то нужна ли запятая.

Подчеркиваю, вопрос о грамматике, как переделать в безупречную, я и сам знаю.

//=====
Чтобы не было сомнений в смысле.

***"Жили-были Петя и Маша, который любил пельмени(,) и которая любила танцевать".*** 
//---
25.10.2014
Видимо, я что-то не внятно спрашиваю. 
Попробую переформулировать вопрос позже.

Answer (score 4):

Некорректна, нарушено согласование подлежащего придаточного с определяемым словом главного. Или Петя и Маша, которые...Или Петя, который..., и Маша, которая.

Данное предложение - сложноподчинённое с однородными придаточными, запятая перед И не нужна (пунктуация как при однородных членах).

Comment: Чем или чем нарушено согласовование?

Comment: "Жили-были Петя и Маша, который любил пельмени и которая любила танцевать". В таком поэтическом контексте с оттенком иронии  конструкция корректна. Грамматика нарушена специально, чтобы внести элемент детскости, игры-сказки, смысл подчёркивается грамматикой. В детских стихах-нелепицах вообще возможна  нелепая грамматика на детский лад. И всё будет корректно.

Comment: Людмила, контест скорее уж иронический. Не о том речь. 
Если грамматика нарушена, то намеренность такого нарушения меня не интересуют.  Что именно нарушено в грамматике. Если снова речь о том, что придаточное должно следовать за определяемым словом, то я уже ответил. Это тенденция, но никак не императивный закон, а значит к грамматике прямого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Нарушена последовательность в схеме построения СПП с двумя придаточными. Параллельное подчинение  оформлено как однородное. Который...и который-однородное.Он, который..., и она, которая...- параллельное, неоднородное. Здесь произошло смешение, нарушение логики подчинения.

Answer (score 3):

"Жили-были Петя и Маша, который любил её(,) и которая любила его"

Предложение сложноподчиненное с двумя придаточными присубстантивными, причем одно относится к имени существительному ПЕТЯ, а другое --- к имени существительному МАША. Одной из ярких структурных особенностей присубстантивных сложноподчиненных предложений является употребление придаточной части непостредственно после опорного для него имени в главной части, то есть ПЕТЯ, КОТОРЫЙ ЛЮБИЛ ЕЕ  и МАША, КОТОРАЯ ЛЮБИЛА ЕГО. Вывод: предложенное для ответа на вопрос предложение построено неверно, и поэтому вопрос о запятой между частями снимается.

Возможны такие варианты построения:1) Жили-были Петя и Маша, которые любили друг друга. Жили-были Петя, который любил Машу, и Маша, которая любила Петю. 2) Если же речь идет о пельменях и танцах, то: Жили-были Петя, который любил пельмени, и Маша, которая любила танцевать. Запятые выделяют придаточные части.

Comment: >Одной из ярких структурных особенностей присубстантивных сложноподчиненных предложений является употребление придаточной части непостредственно после опорного для него имени в главной части,   
  
Это не императивно, т.е. относится к области стилистики, а не грамматики.

***На кухне была Фрекен Бок в новом фартуке и со скалкой в руке (....), которая занималась изготовление плюшек.***
Это не цитата, если что, но чем фраза плоха?!
В скобках можно еще хоть роман написать.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматика некорректная.

Это СПП с однородными придаточными определительными, причем в качестве опорного существительного в главном предложении выступает словосочетание Петя и Маша.

Союзное слово КОТОРЫЙ замещает опорное существительное и должно иметь ту же форму числа, причем в обоих однородных предложениях, например: "Жили Петя и Маша, которые любили друг друга и которые никогда не расставались".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Как доказать, что грамматика нестандартная

1) Во второй части мы имеем союзную связь ОДНОРОДНЫХ придаточных (который... и которая...). Отметим, что неоднородные придаточные союзами не соединяются.

2) По определению каждое из ОДНОРОДНЫХ придаточных должно относиться ко всему главному предложению или к одному и тому (опорному) члену в главном предложении, а между ними существует сочинительная связь (союзная или бессоюзная). Такая грамматика называется однородным СОПОДЧИНЕНИЕМ.

3) В приведенном примере этот грамматический закон НАРУШЕН: однородные придаточные, связанные союзом И, относятся к РАЗНЫМ опорным существительным.

Comment: София, но от вас-то уж точно не ожидал предложений по правке - поле того, как я сказал, что она мне не нужна. Да еще с таким грубым искажением смысла вопроса.(((

Вы не глубоко не правы, полагая, что тут опрорное слово "Петя и Маша". Тут, по задумке, мыслится два опорных. "Петя" для "который..." и "Маша" для "которая". В этом весь и смысл вопроса. Другое дело, сумел ли я его передать.

Comment: Не понимаю, о каком искажении Вы говорите. Мне понятно то содержание, которое вы хотите выразить, но форма, которую вы хотите для этого использовать, НЕ МОЖЕТ выразить этого содержания. И я в ответе объясняю, почему не может. Вообще СПП имеют строгую структуру, в грамматике подробно расписано, что им можно и что нельзя. Я пользуюсь книгой "Современный русский синтаксис" (2013г), и там две трети всего содержания посвящено анализу СПП разных видов, в частности рассматривается определительный тип.

Comment: Какая бы ни была у Вас задумка относительно опорного слова, реализовать  ее в задуманном виде Вы не можете, не нарушая основ грамматики. Опорным словом здесь будет или сочетание Петя и Маша, или одна Маша: "Пришли Петя и Маша, которую мы еще не видели". Или: "Пришли Петя и Маша, увидев которых/которую.." Это ВЕСЬ набор авторских возможностей при использовании грамматической формы ССП с придаточным определительным.

Comment: >Не понимаю, о каком искажении Вы говорите.  
  
Об искажении смысла вопроса, которое Вы привнесли своим "пониманием". Фраза создавалась специально для того, чтобы задать вопрос о грамматике фразы с двумя параллельными придаточными, соединенными союзом. А Вы все свели к банальной правке "под редактора" с соподчинением или перестановкой порядка. Как-то даже обидно от вас такое слышать.

Comment: "Жили-были Петя и Маша: он любил ее и она любила его". Делаем замену. "Жили-были Петя и Маша, который любил ее и которая любила его". Грамматика абсолютно новая, основанная на параллельном сопоставлении: "Петя и Маша, который и которая", но понять смысл можно, если структура предложений достаточна проста.  Запятую не ставим, считая, что придаточные предложения однородные.  Такую конструкцию лучше назвать фигурой речи, и я не уверена, что нечто подобное можно встретить в существующих текстах.

Comment: >"Жили-были Петя и Маша: он любил ее и она любила его" Делаем замену.   
  
Бога ради, только не это. Зачем что-то менять во фразе с корректной граммтикой? Стобы сделать её некорректной (как вы полагаете)? Разве так демонстрируют некорректность грамматики? Вон Антонаова правильно начала: в этой фпаже нарушено то-то и то-то. Да вся беда втом, что как выясняется ничего не нарушено. Только на слух немного корявая.  
Напрашивается формулировка, что *опорное слово для одного придаточного не может находиться между другим опороным словом и придаточным к нему*. **Может и так, но почему так??7**

Comment: Некорректность вашей грамматике я объяснила в дополнении к ответу: однородные придаточные должны относиться К ОДНОМУ ОПОРНОМУ СЛОВУ. Это закон для всех однородных структур.